# How does LastPass chrome extension remember logged in user after being opened in incognito mode?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, session-cookies, incognito-mode, lastpass

I logged in to LastPass chrome extension in the regular browsing mode. Then I opened a new incognito tab and the LastPass extension still knows who I am. How did they do that? I need that exact behaviour for my chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the extension is enabled in the incognito, it will automatically get the credentials logged in to the regular browser. You may check this [link](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2384484/enable-disable-chrome-extensions-incognito-mode.html) on *How to Enable and Disable Chrome Extensions in Incognito Mode*. You may also check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) on how to use **`incognito`** manifest key with either **`spanning`** or **`split`** to specify how this extension will behave if allowed to run in incognito mode.